# How to create a Seurat Object from GSE data set?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, seurat

I know that we can create Seurat object from cell ranger output files(barcode, features, matrix). But I have a GSE single cell data set in csv format. How do I create a Seurat object out of that?

Thanks.

> `a = read.csv(<csv file >, header = TRUE)`

> `b = t(a)`

> `c = CreateSeuratObject(counts = b, project = "my_single_cell", min.cells = 3, min.features = 200)`

`Error in CreateAssayObject(counts = counts, min.cells = min.cells, min.features = min.features,  :`

No cell names (colnames) names present in the input matrix

> `dput(a[1:10, 1:10])`

````
2.0293824672699, 0, 0, 1.67916893959045, 1.25670552253723, 0, 
0, 2.35019993782043, 0), Lypla1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), Gm37988 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Tcea1 = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Atp6v1h = c(0, 0, 0, 1.69750428199768, 
0, 1.25670552253723, 0, 0, 0, 0), Rb1cc1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), X4732440D04Rik = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Pcmtd1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.25670552253723, 0, 2.10469627380371, 
    0, 0), Gm26901 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("AAACCCATCTGGAAGG-WT1", 
"AAACGAACAACTCGTA-WT1", "AAACGAACACAGACGA-WT1", "AAACGAATCACGAACT-WT1", 
"AAACGAATCAGGGTAG-WT1", "AAACGCTAGCTGACTT-WT1", "AAACGCTTCGACCTAA-WT1", 
"AAAGAACAGAATCCCT-WT1", "AAAGTCCAGAGTGACC-WT1", "AAAGTCCAGTAAACAC-WT1"
), class = "data.frame")```
>
````

Comment: How does the data look? Please include a part of the input (with `dput(a[1:10, 1:10])` for example).

Answer (score 1):

The original table seems to have cells on rows and genes in columns, with the cell names in the first column. To get correct rownames, try this:

```
a = read.csv(data.csv, row.names = 1)

b = t(a)

c = CreateSeuratObject(counts = b, project = "my_single_cell", min.cells = 3, min.features = 200)
```

Edit: The table seems to contain normalized expression values instead of raw counts. Seurat may not be the right tool for working with that kind of data.

Comment: I put the complete out in the original question as you suggested. Is there a way to convert this data and import it into a Seurat object?

Comment: @raj I added the `t()` and `CreateSeuratObject()` commands for clarity, but they are the same you already had in your question. Did it work, or if not, which error did you get?

Comment: yes, that worked for the Seurat object creation. Thanks.